# MySQL query dev like SQL Server

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm coming from a SQL Server background, and I'm used to using the view designer to build queries for me. I'm referring to the screen that has the 4 areas, tables and relationships (which you build by dragging from one table to another) at the top, columns in use and filters next, then the SQL code, then the results of the query when you run it at the bottom. This lets me build SQL code when linking tables together so I can copy and paste into my applications.

I've downloaded and installed MySQL Workbench on my Mac, and connected to my shared hosting DB on Media Temple.

But I can't seem to find anything similar in MySQL Workbench to the screen described above from SQL Server, something that writes the SQL code for all the joins for you. I've also tried Sequel Pro too.

Can anyone help..?

Edit: If MySQL Workbench can't help me, is there any other software for Mac that might..?

Comment: Workbench does not have such a feature.

Comment: Ok, thanks ypercube, do you know of any Mac software for MySQL that does...?

Comment: You should try looking at Sequel Pro. That's what I use for MySQL on my Mac.

Comment: SQLyog has this, but no Mac version apparently...

Answer (score 0):

Try Navicat for MySQL http://navicat.com/en/products/navicat_mysql/mysql_detail_mac.html It has a query builder view similar to what you are used to and a 30 day evaluation period